# Compiler Error when using a struct

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I'm getting a strange compiler error initializing a struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct RadarData
{
    unsigned int messageID : 32;
    unsigned int time : 32;
    float az;
    float el;
};
struct RadarData sendData;

sendData.az = 25;
sendData.el = 10;
sendData.messageID = 1;
sendData.time = 100;
```

This looks fine to me according to a few different tutorials, but on two different machines, I'm getting the following error when compiling:

> testserver.c:15:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘.’ token
>   testserver.c:16:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘.’ token
>   testserver.c:17:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘.’ token
>   testserver.c:18:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘.’ token

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: can you paste the entire code snippet? Including which function this appears in..

Comment: look at the line numbers - I think this _is_ his real code (I thought he might be forgetting the function for a moment as well, but, perhaps not...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sendData.az = 25;
```

Statements like this must be inside a function. If you want to initialize the struct, there's a different syntax for that:

```
struct RadarData sendData = { 25, 10, 1, 100 };
```

Answer (score 3):

If I'm looking at your code right (and that's the complete relevant code), then you're placing statements outside of a function. That's not right.